# Legendre symbols with huge "p"s

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am in doubt with an exercise - I need to calculate 
$$\left(205\mid853\right)$$

I would use the fact Legendre's symbols are multiplicative, but then I would have something like

$$\left(5\mid853\right)\left(41\mid853\right)$$

and it would not help much with Gauss lemma, since it would mean having sequences $(853-1)/2$ longs to multiply, to operate $\mod 853$, and so on.

Is there a faster trick I don't see?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(205 |853)=-1$. see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what+are+the+quadratic+residue+modulo+853.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity

If you can't solve the problem with this tool, please comment out and I'll write a more complete answer.

Comment: That solves - but I cannot use it, unfortunately is not in the programme of this course.

Comment: Then, as far as I know, the only way is brute force. Can you use a computer program?